# twitter bootstrap has reset my styles for my divs and font

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I configured my page with a menu I just created and set my css for the menu items but then I added twitter-bootstrap and all this padding and font sizing changed my page when I've set my font sizes and padding or could it be something else that twitter-boostrap is changing

Leave a message if you know what to do to set reset my page

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your web site css `<link>` after the bootstrap.css `<link>`, that way it will override whatever is in bootstrap.css. If this doesn't work, you will have to defined the desired padding and font sizes in your site css. bootstrap.css has a reset that zeroes out all padding and margins for all html elements. This is a good practice anyways to give your website maximum uniformity across different browsers.

Comment: Yes, first load your bootstrap.css then load your bootstrap-overrides.css.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your custom CSS after bootstrap CSS does, as Brian said.

That will work in case your CSS overwrites all properties of Bootstrap that applies to your menu.

If not that case, you should define in your CSS all properties that matters. Use tools like firebug or similar to detect which properties are being defined by Bootstrap and not for your CSS.

Hope it helps.